# northwind sql: getting Order Details by CustomerID and CategoryID

Tags: sql, northwind

```
   select OD.* from [Order Details] as OD where OD.OrderID = Orders.OrderID and 
   OD.ProductID = Products.ProductID and
   Products.CategoryID = 1 and
   Orders.CustomerID = 'ALFKI'
```

the errors i get:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "Orders.OrderID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "Products.ProductID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "Products.CategoryID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "Orders.CustomerID" could not be bound.

Answer (score 0):

You have just one table alias defined which is OD.

You fergot to join Orders and Products table.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually `JOIN` to the `Orders` and  `Products` tables, something like this:

```
select OD.* 
from [Order Details] OD
    join Orders O on OD.OrderID = O.OrderID 
    join Products P on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID 
where P.CategoryID = 1 and
    O.CustomerID = 'ALFKI'
```